# ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to pull data from a Microsoft Access database using Python. I used pyodbc module and my code is following:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=directory_that_access_the_database;'
    r'DATABASE=name_of_the_database;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from database where database.date = #mm/dd/yyyy#')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

then it returns an error as

> ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on database. (-1907) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I already checked other stack overflows, and I also enable my permissions on this specific database through the `ribbon--Users` and Group Permissions, but the error still returned. My idea is that there is some detail that I missed when I wanted to enable the permissions, but I really do not know how to pull it through. Can someone help me with this issue, please?

Answer (score 1):

Access ODBC connection strings do not use the `Database=` or `Trusted_Connection=` arguments. The `DBQ=` argument should be the complete path for the database file, including the file name and extension.

So this won't work

```py
connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\Public;'
    r'DATABASE=Database1.accdb;'
)
```

whereas this will work

```py
connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;'
)
```